# Login to Facebook with Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

In my Windows Phone application I am using the Facebook C# SDK - http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

I registered an application on Facebook and after first login I see this screen
(asking for permission on Windows Phone):

[image]

If I click apply in then emulator it logs in successfully, but if I click apply on a real device it redirects me to a login page again. Why does it do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Login to facebook (Windows Phone)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10738134/50447)

Comment: Is it still redirecting the real phone back to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request ?

Comment: after success login it returns url with permission  error and then redirect to login page

Comment: @RowlandShaw I tried this also and I'm running into the same issue. Strange because my script was working perfectly last week. Now it keeps redirecting me to the login page, saying the user denied permission.

Answer (score 0):

You should check is enabled cookies (or like that storage, where facebook saves a Authorization Key) in the browser or system. I am not worked with WP7, it is a first idea.